# Google Sheets: Highlight First Instances within Range of Cells that are Specific Amounts Greater Than a Cell

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-sheets

I have a vehicle data sheet with 3 different columns (L7:N56) to track the odometer reading during services or at the beginning/end of a trip.

1. I want to be able to check all three columns (L7:N56) and highlight the first instance that is greater than or equal (>=) to **3000** miles greater than the last oil change odometer in cell M4 as a warning that we will need an oil change soon (M4+3000).
2. I also want to be able to highlight the first instance that is greater than or equal (>=) to **5000** miles greater than the last oil change odometer in M4 (M4+5000).

I do not want to highlight every value that meets the criteria (no duplicates), only the first instances.

[example of vehicle data spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxVn8.png)

Comment: While an image may give some indication of intention, it doesn't provide an actual way for the volunteer contributors here to access data, develop a solution, test outcomes or leave working formulas. I suggest that you share a link to a copy of this spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: cond form]

If you want such a result in the **range L5:N56**, just use,for `RED`, the custom formula:

```
=L5:N5=query(index(sort(unique(flatten($L$5:$N$56)),1,1)),"select Col1 where Col1 >="&$M$2+5000&"Limit 1",0)
```

and, for `YELLOW`, the formula:

```
=L5:N5=query(index(sort(unique(flatten($L$5:$N$56)),1,1)),"select Col1 where Col1 >="&$M$2+3000&"Limit 1",0)
```

[Link to test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gfGnA6Z7NW5A0nTNDCyM-Q152HXQ_XQo84ag9v9ydT8/edit?usp=sharing)